# CSS wrapping and hiding text within a table

Tags: html, css

Here is my table: (removed and added rendered HTML at the bottom.)

```
<table style="width: 100%; white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden;">
    <tbody><tr>
        <th>
            Department
        </th>
        <th>
            Function
        </th>
        <th>
            Process
        </th>
        <th style="max-width: 75px;">
            Procedure
        </th>
        <th>
        </th>
    </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Legal Process</td>
            <td>Setup and Maintenance</td>
            <td>New placement scrub</td>
            <td>Review of newly placed accounts to determine if there is missing information or incorrect information before collection efforts are begun</td>

            <td align="center"><a href="/MasterList/Details/1">Details</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Legal Process</td>
            <td>Setup and Maintenance</td>
            <td>685 Queue/ Midland chargeoff balance issue</td>
            <td>Review and correction of Midland accounts that where placed with differing charge off and current principal balances</td>

            <td align="center"><a href="/MasterList/Details/2">Details</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Legal Process</td>
            <td>Lawsuit and Judgment Process</td>
            <td>Skip Trace</td>
            <td>Re-Serve Request CA</td>

            <td align="center"><a href="/MasterList/Details/3">Details</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Legal Process</td>
            <td>Lawsuit and Judgment Process</td>
            <td>Skip Trace</td>
            <td>Re-serve Request ID</td>

            <td align="center"><a href="/MasterList/Details/4">Details</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Legal Process</td>
            <td>Lawsuit and Judgment Process</td>
            <td>Suit Referral</td>
            <td>Barclays Suit Referral</td>

            <td align="center"><a href="/MasterList/Details/5">Details</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Legal Process</td>
            <td>Lawsuit and Judgment Process</td>
            <td>Suit Referral</td>
            <td>Capital One CRS Procedure</td>

            <td align="center"><a href="/MasterList/Details/6">Details</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Litigation Support</td>
            <td>Admin Mailroom &amp; Doc Production</td>
            <td>Oregon ten day demand letter</td>
            <td>Ten day demand letter is sent to the debtor</td>

            <td align="center"><a href="/MasterList/Details/7">Details</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Litigation Support</td>
            <td>Admin Mailroom &amp; Doc Production</td>
            <td>Oregon debtor exam</td>
            <td>Debtor exam  forwarded to court for issuing</td>

            <td align="center"><a href="/MasterList/Details/8">Details</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Litigation Support</td>
            <td>Admin Mailroom &amp; Doc Production</td>
            <td>Oregon debtor exam</td>
            <td>Debtor exam returned from court and forwarded to the Process Server for service</td>

            <td align="center"><a href="/MasterList/Details/9">Details</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Litigation Support</td>
            <td>Lawsuit and Judgment Process</td>
            <td>Oregon subpoena </td>
            <td>Subpoena forwarded to the Process Server for service</td>

            <td align="center"><a href="/MasterList/Details/10">Details</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Finance</td>
            <td>H/R - Payroll</td>
            <td>Benefits</td>
            <td>Benefits Signup</td>

            <td align="center"><a href="/MasterList/Details/11">Details</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Finance</td>
            <td>H/R - Payroll</td>
            <td>Benefits</td>
            <td>Benefits Summary</td>

            <td align="center"><a href="/MasterList/Details/12">Details</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Finance</td>
            <td>H/R - Payroll</td>
            <td>New Hire</td>
            <td>Background Check</td>

            <td align="center"><a href="/MasterList/Details/13">Details</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Finance</td>
            <td>H/R - Payroll</td>
            <td>New Hire</td>
            <td>ISI Orientation - Drug Test</td>

            <td align="center"><a href="/MasterList/Details/14">Details</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Finance</td>
            <td>Processing</td>
            <td>Client Remittances</td>
            <td>Asset Acceptance Remit</td>

            <td align="center"><a href="/MasterList/Details/15">Details</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Finance</td>
            <td>Processing</td>
            <td>Client Remittances</td>
            <td>End of Month Remits</td>

            <td align="center"><a href="/MasterList/Details/16">Details</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Finance</td>
            <td>Processing</td>
            <td>Cost Audits</td>
            <td>Internal Cost Audits</td>

            <td align="center"><a href="/MasterList/Details/17">Details</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Finance</td>
            <td>Processing</td>
            <td>Cost Audits</td>
            <td>Weekly Cost Duplicates</td>

            <td align="center"><a href="/MasterList/Details/18">Details</a></td>
        </tr>
</tbody></table>
```

Currently it isn't wrapping the text so the table looks nice and clean.  However I have some REALLY long Procedures names and so the table is pushed off the page.

What I want to happen is: if the name is longer than the width of the cell it hides the text.

I really only want the procedure to have width constrains.

[image]

I have added no additional CSS to this project outside of what is included in the asp.net MVC4 starter template.

Comment: Please post the rendered HTML, not whatever language that is. CSS too.

Comment: it would be better if you posted the rendered markup rather than the MVC3/Razor. That way we can put it in a fiddle and play around (inlcude what css you have also please)

Comment: @PaulSullivan I've added the rendered HTML.

Comment: @TwiNight There is no CSS added outside of what the browser gives it by default.  This is a blank canvas.  The only CSS I have added is included inline `<table style="width: 100%; white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden;">`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you can add a class to each "procedure" column (and the header, as well), like so:

```
 <tr>
   <td>Litigation Support</td>
   <td>Admin Mailroom &amp; Doc Production</td>
   <td>Oregon debtor exam</td>
   <td class="proc">Debtor exam  forwarded to court for issuing</td>

   <td align="center"><a href="/MasterList/Details/8">Details</a></td>
 </tr>
```

you can reign the text in like so:

```
.proc {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  max-width: 150px;
}
```

```css
.proc {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  max-width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<table style="width: 100%; white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden;">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>
        Department
      </th>
      <th>
        Function
      </th>
      <th>
        Process
      </th>
      <th class="proc">
        Procedure
      </th>
      <th>
      </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Legal Process</td>
      <td>Setup and Maintenance</td>
      <td>New placement scrub</td>
      <td class="proc">Review of newly placed accounts to determine if there is missing information or incorrect information before collection efforts are begun</td>

      <td align="center"><a href="/MasterList/Details/1">Details</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Legal Process</td>
      <td>Setup and Maintenance</td>
      <td>685 Queue/ Midland chargeoff balance issue</td>
      <td class="proc">Review and correction of Midland accounts that where placed with differing charge off and current principal balances</td>

      <td align="center"><a href="/MasterList/Details/2">Details</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Legal Process</td>
      <td>Lawsuit and Judgment Process</td>
      <td>Skip Trace</td>
      <td class="proc">Re-Serve Request CA</td>

      <td align="center"><a href="/MasterList/Details/3">Details</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Legal Process</td>
      <td>Lawsuit and Judgment Process</td>
      <td>Skip Trace</td>
      <td class="proc">Re-serve Request ID</td>

      <td align="center"><a href="/MasterList/Details/4">Details</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Legal Process</td>
      <td>Lawsuit and Judgment Process</td>
      <td>Suit Referral</td>
      <td class="proc">Barclays Suit Referral</td>

      <td align="center"><a href="/MasterList/Details/5">Details</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Legal Process</td>
      <td>Lawsuit and Judgment Process</td>
      <td>Suit Referral</td>
      <td class="proc">Capital One CRS Procedure</td>

      <td align="center"><a href="/MasterList/Details/6">Details</a></td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you, worked like a charm.  I tried to add text-overflow inline to the table it self but this didn't work.  Only worked when I added it to the css file.  Thanks again.

Comment: @JamesWilson You don't have to add a class you can just do it through css ;)

Answer (score 1):

Part of the problem is that display:table is by nature flexible - that is, the size of the table contents is what determines the size of the table.  If you want to make sure your table is exactly the size you define, you need to set `{table-layout:fixed}` as part of your table's CSS rule.  That carries the additional requirement of specifying a width for at least n-1 of n table columns, or the table will automatically give equal space to each column.  I recommend setting each column width in percentages aside from the last column, which will automatically take up the remaining space not given to the other columns.  Then use Paul Roub's solution to cut off the remaining content that doesn't fit into the column width.  The `text-overflow:ellipsis` property is not supported in all browsers, but it's the best you're going to get without resorting to javascript.  That said, if you do want to resort to javascript, I highly recommend the "dotdotdot" library: http://dotdotdot.frebsite.nl/

Comment: Thanks for all of that added info, every it helps for learning more and more. :)

Answer (score 1):

A working [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/HT3Eu/1/)

//css

```
.thetable>tbody>tr>td+td+td+td {
    overflow:hidden;
    max-width:200px;
    white-space:nowrap;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that method as well. :)